# Convert between Gregorian and Hijri dates in Vue3 Component

Tags: datepicker, vuejs3, vue-component, momentjs

I wrote a vue.js code component that shows two fields for the Hijri and Gregorian dates. When the user chooses the Gregorian date, the Gregorian to Hijri conversion function converts the value and displays the result in the Hijri date field smoothly. But when the process is applied in reverse, such that the user chooses the Hijri date, the value is not received in the conversion function from Hijri to Gregorian and is not passed to the Gregorian field!!
i use : MAZ-UI(MazPicker - MazInput) , moment , moment-hijri and Hijridate picker web component, simple and can be integrated easily with any frameworks by
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/abublihi/datepicker-hijri@v1.1/build/datepicker-hijri.js"></script>`
How can I ensure that the Hijri date that was chosen from the Hijri calendar was received in the conversion function? Why is the converted value not passed to the Gregorian date field?
How can the problem be solved?

```
<template>
    <div style="margin: 100px">
        <label for="hijri-date">التاريخ بالهجري:</label>
        <MazInput id="hijri-date" v-model="hijriDate" />
        <datepicker-hijri
            reference="hijri-date"
            placement="bottom"
            @update:model-value="convertToGregorian"
            date-format="iYYYY/iMM/iDD"
            :selected-date="convertToHijri"
            placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
        ></datepicker-hijri>
        <!-- ^^^^^^^^ -->
        <br />
        <label for="gregorian-date">التاريخ بالميلادي:</label>
        <MazPicker locale="ar" format="YYYY-MM-DD" :inputDateStyle="{ dateStyle: 'short' }" id="gregorian-date" v-model="gregorianDate" @update:model-value="convertToHijri" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from "moment"
import momentHijri from "moment-hijri"
import MazInput from "maz-ui/components/MazInput"
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            hijriDate: "",
            gregorianDate: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        convertToGregorian() {
            const hijriMoment = momentHijri(this.hijriDate, "iYYYY/iMM/iDD")
            const gregorianDate = hijriMoment.toDate()
            this.gregorianDate = moment(gregorianDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            console.log(this.gregorianDate)
        },
        convertToHijri() {
            const gregorianMoment = moment(this.gregorianDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
            const hijriDate = momentHijri(gregorianMoment.toDate()).format("iYYYY/iMM/iDD")
            this.hijriDate = hijriDate
            console.log(this.hijriDate)
        },
    },
}
</script>
<style>
input {
    border: 1px solid rgb(137, 136, 136);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    width: 13rem;
    color: rgba(90, 89, 89, 0.877);
    font-size: medium;
}
</style>
```

I was trying to convert the date from Hijri to Gregorian and from Gregorian to Hijri by choosing the date from the custom calendar. I succeeded in doing this with the Gregorian date field, where I was able to make the user choose the appropriate Gregorian date, then pass the value to the conversion function from Gregorian to Hijri, and display the result in the Hijri date field. But what I did not succeed in applying was the opposite of the process, as I mentioned for the Hijri calendar. I would like to apply this to the Hijri date field. I hope you can help me